# Why do compilers perform aliasing if it slows runtime performance?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, clang, llvm

I've been learning C and computer science topics out of pure interest and it's led me to becoming interested in compilers. Everything I've read tells me that aliasing results in slower assembly output that needs to reload values upon every iteration.

I've been able to get a slight increase on some benchmarks with the Intel C / C++ compiler using the flag `-fno-alias`. GCC and Clang / LLVM do not have an equivalent flag. There is `-fargument-noalias` and `-fargument-noalias-global` which I am guessing disables aliasing on function arguments — **please correct me if I'm wrong** — but I have not noticed it making any difference in runtime or even compile-time performance.

Does the statement

> Aliasing affects performance by preventing the compiler from doing certain optimizations.

always hold true, and what are the benefits of compiler aliasing? Why is it a feature of modern compilers that cannot be easily turned off with a flag except for the Intel compiler? Will compiling without aliasing result in code non-conformant to ABI standards?

Comment: They don't *perform* aliasing. Your program might perform aliasing. The compiler either allows you to perform aliasing, or assumes you didn't and then writes machine code that doesn't work if you did aliasing.

Comment: What would be the full list of options passed to the compiler? Or you're just passing it the `-fno-alias`?

Comment: Aliasing is not a feature of compilers. It is a habbit of programmers. These options tell the compiler that you promise not to do this.

Comment: `void f(int *x, int *y) {*x += *y;}` <- if x and y are the same pointer, that's aliasing

Comment: @user253751  I guess I was really confused. I did not realize that aliasing using pointers in C is the same thing. I assumed compile aliasing was some kind of reorganization of code the compiler performed itself into assembly. Thank you for the example

Comment: @Shark also -O3, but in both compilations of some benchmarks from a github repo. Now that I understand what is meant by aliasing, I am guessing I possibly compiled with some of the code in the benchmarks broken, or that the flag allows the Intel compiler to do certain optimizations only possible if no aliasing is assumed for the entire program.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compilers don't perform aliasing. Your program might perform aliasing.

The compiler either allows you to perform aliasing, or assumes you didn't and then writes machine code that doesn't work if you did aliasing.

For example, you write code like this:

```
void f(int *x, int *y, int *z) {
    *y += *x;
    *z += *x;
}
```

The function just adds `*x` to `*y` and `*z`, right? So the assembly code should be like this, right? (I wrote the assembly code in pseudo-C)

```
eax = argument x
ebx = argument y
ecx = *eax
*ebx += ecx
ebx = argument z
*ebx += ecx
```

***Wrong.*** If `y` and `x` point to the same place, this assembly code doesn't work the same as the C code because it uses the *old* `*x`. To work right it would have to be like this:

```
eax = argument x
ebx = argument y
ecx = *eax
*ebx += ecx
ebx = argument z
ecx = *eax // extra instruction
*ebx += ecx
```

That's one more instruction and it's only useful if `x==y`, but the compiler has to put it there just in case. *Aliasing* means that `*x` and `*y` are different names for the same variable. If the compiler assumes that `x` and `y` can't be the same pointer (i.e. there isn't aliasing) then it can skip this instruction, so there are less instructions and the program runs faster.

You can tell the compiler they don't alias by using the word `restrict`, like this:

```
void f(int *restrict x, int *restrict y, int *restrict z) {
    *y += *x;
    *z += *x;
}
```

`-fno-alias` tells the Intel compiler that aliasing can't happen anywhere. This is likely to create bugs *somewhere* because parameters do alias sometimes - although it might work fine on small programs where none of them do. `restrict` is more carefully targeted at the specific parameters that you know don't alias.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and clarification, as well as the examples. I wonder what a real use case would be of using pointers without aliasing where you may specify restrict for greater optimization.

Comment: @eyeseaevan just about any function with multiple pointer arguments with the same type. A lot of standard library functions (e.g. strcpy) have `restrict`

Answer (score 4):

Aliasing is all about what assumptions the compiler can be allowed to make regarding certain variables. C compilers work on translation unit basis, meaning it will not likely know what's going on in another translation unit. Everything with "external linkage", both variables and functions, may be accessed from different translation units. So generally the compiler won't know how such a function was called.

For example:

```c
int func1 (int* x, int* y)
{
  *y = 2;
  *x = 1;
  if(*y == 1)
  {
    return 1;
  }
  return 2;
}
```

If the compiler doesn't know how this function was called, then at the `if` statement it cannot assume that `*y` is `2` because `x` might point at the same location as `y` - they may alias. And so the compiler must load the value into memory and check to make sure.

---

But in the case we change the pointer types to something that is not allowed to alias:

```c
int func2 (double* x, int* y)
{
  *y = 2;
  *x = 1;
  if(*y == 1)
  {
    return 1;
  }
  return 2;
}
```

Now the compiler is free to assume that `*x` doesn't touch `*y` so this function will always return `2` and may be optimized accordingly. The rules for what types that are allowed to alias are informally called "strict pointer aliasing".

---

Similar things could probably be achieved with gcc options, but there's no reason to do that... because all the way back since C99, we have C standard support to document to the compiler that two values are not aliases, namely the `restrict` pointer qualifier:

```
int func3 (int* x, int* restrict y)
{
  *y = 2;
  *x = 1;
  if(*y == 1)
  {
    return 1;
  }
  return 2;
}
```

This tells the compiler that all accesses to the value that `y` points at are made through the pointer `y`. So now the compiler is free to assume that the function always returns `2`. This is a contract between the programmer and the compiler - the programmer has to fulfill it by not passing pointers to the same variable etc.

---

The "all accesses go through this pointer" is important, because that also includes globals.

```c
int x;

int func4 (int* y)
{
  *y = 2;
  x = 1;
  if(*y == 1)
  {
    return 1;
  }
  return 2;
}
```

Here the compiler can't assume that `y` wasn't updated, since it can't assume that the function wasn't called as:

```c
extern int x;
func4(&x);
```

With `restrict` we protect against that scenario as well. Similarly, had we declared `x` as `static int x;` instead of a global, that would have served the same purpose, since the compiler can then assume that `x` isn't accessed outside the current translation unit.

You can peek at machine code generated by these various examples here https://godbolt.org/z/68Earfafn. As you can tell, the versions where the compiler had to assume that both pointers could alias were less efficient, since it has to load the value and also execute a compare instruction (which adds a branch).

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comments to my question, I realized I was very confused about what compilers meant by aliasing. I mistakenly understood it as a separate feature of the compiler, but rather it is a situation found in code. Aliasing is a way of using pointers or references in systems programming languages like C and C++ to access the same memory location.

As a result, two different names are used to refer to the same variable or object in memory. This can lead to unexpected behavior when one of the pointers or references modifies the memory location, and the other pointer or reference is unaware of this change.

If you change the value of the variable using a pointer, the value of the variable in the functions or calls accessed by the other pointer(s) will also also change. Because the compiler has to make sure changes made through one pointer are visible through the other pointer, it limits the various optimization techniques compilers can perform and typically leads additional assembly instructions needing to fetch the referenced variable upon every iteration of the function or loop as it is prone to change by another function or call in the program throughout the runtime.