# What are the performance and memory differences between a local array and a static const local array?

Tags: c

I am trying to decide whether to use

```
int x[] = {/*some numbers*/};
```

or

```
static const int x[] = {/*some numbers*/};
```

My understanding is that the first version will remake the array every function call, which seems wasteful, while the second will make a global variable accessible only by the function, and the memory distance might be less performant. (const is just there for decoration in C, and to show you that the numbers won't change).

I first made the array in global scope, but then I thought it might be better to limit the scope. Ofcourse, maybe the best thing to do would be to just do it normal and have the array remade every time. I don't know.

Comment: A local static variable is initialized *once* and then shared between all calls to the function. So you save on initialization. *But* if the function modifies the data of the variable it will be modified for all calls, the function is no longer properly reentrant. With that said, if you have constant data that should not change between calls, then making the variable static might save a few cycles each call.

Comment: With that said, create two examples (one for each method) and then call the function a million times, measuring the time and calculating an average. But remember to build with optimization enabled, and make sure that the compiler doesn't just optimize away the function call itself (it needs to have some side-effect, which isn't printing to the console as that's going to skew the measurements).

Comment: See for yourself... https://godbolt.org/z/E9o3Kdo1G

Comment: @Raildex Thanks, but I don't really know ASM so I would need an interpretarion of this (I read about L0 L1 registers in some other thread so I recognize that). Also, my understanding is that const in C++ is vastly different than the one in C (mainly in that it actually does something)

Comment: @sneaker You don't need to know a lot about it, just that the various `mov...` instructions move data in memory. In this case they stack the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes `static const` will likely perform better and never worse than the alternative without qualifiers. Without them there's a chance that the data will get loaded onto the stack at each function call.

Reducing the scope as much as possible is good practice.

> const is just there for decoration in C, and to show you that the numbers won't change

This isn't true, especially not on ROM-based systems like microcontrollers. On those systems, `const` often makes the difference between RAM allocation and flash allocation.

Furthermore, there's a bunch of more subtle things related to `const` such as pointer aliasing decisions made by the compiler, meaning it can improve performance in some situations. Check out my recent answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/75854539/584518. There are several situations in those examples where `static` and/or `const` improves performance.